# Aiplane mode key not working in GUI but working in TTY

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, airplane-mode

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on Xiaomi Mi Air 12.5. The keyboard has aiplane mode key. And when i press this key on TTY and change to GUI, i see that airplane mode is toggled. But if i press this key on GUI (gnome 3) then airplane mode is not turn on/off. In GUI the key doesn't work. How does it fix?

Comment: I see the same behavior on Lenovo Yoga 900.